# INDEX array formula for one value and then another? Not multiple criteria... Sequential criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there any way to display two "sets" of INDEX results one after the other?

I have the following array formula to display all employees working on a certain job:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(masterlist[[NAME]:[NAME]], SMALL(IF(D18=masterlist[[JOB]:[JOB]], ROW(masterlist[[NAME]:[NAME]])-1,""), ROW()-19)),"")`

Where "masterlist" is the table containing my data and D18 is the Job # search field. Essentially if you enter a Job # it will pull all employees working on that job.

In the resulting list, there are employees with "Foreman" and "Operator" titles that are displayed in whichever order the source "masterlist" table is sorted.

I've changed the original array formula to this one in order to show only the Foremen:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(masterlist[[NAME]:[NAME]], SMALL(IF((E18=masterlist[[JOB]:[JOB]])*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("foreman",masterlist[[TITLE]:[TITLE]]))), ROW(masterlist[[NAME]:[NAME]])-1,""), ROW()-19)),"")`

But I also want to show the Operators in the same list AFTER the Foremen. I've tried INDEXing twice, CONCATENATING, etc. with no luck.

Is there any way to append one INDEX formula to another? Or a way to recursively INDEX for one value and then another?

Comment: can you use {"foreman","other search"} and make the whole formula an array ? I don't actually know if this will work just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to **cascade** `INDEX()` formulas to retrieve multiple instances of data.  Say we have:

[image]

and we want to retrieve the "Jim" data.  We could use an `AGGREGATE()` formula or a `FILTER()` formula or in **E1** enter:

```
=MATCH("Jim",A:A,0)
```

and in **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("Jim",INDEX(A:A,E1+1):INDEX(A:A,9999),0)+E1,"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Now with each Jim row-number, we can easily capture the ages.

The key issue is that each index formula begins one row below the previous index formula.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense.I'm not at my computer to test, but with this would I be able to scan for new data once the "Jim Loop" is complete? Like, say it found rows 11, 13, 15, 17 with Jim's name and there are no more Jim's - could the formula then search for "Ralph" and continue with the list in Col E?

Comment: @AdamKaufman  You would need a different phrase for the `IFERROR()`